# Does boost::crc_32_type generate any exceptions?

Tags: c++, boost, exception

Assuming that BufferLenght is >=0 and *Buffer is a valid buffer will the following code generate exceptions? What about if Buffer is invalid? Are there any cases where it can generate exceptions and how to handle them?

```
unsigned CRC32(const void *Buffer, unsigned BufferLength)
    {
    boost::crc_32_type result;
    result.process_bytes(Buffer, BufferLength);
    return result.checksum();
    }
```

Comment: if `Buffer` is invalid and `BufferLength` is greater zero, it will yield undefined behaviour and most likely crash the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost CRC looks to be exception neutral.

- no exceptions are documented
- no exceptions are thrown from crc.hpp

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to crc.hpp. I examined it and really there is no throw in there.